# Installing Windows 7 on a Dell server

Tags: windows-7, dell-poweredge

I have a Dell server T420 on which I'm trying to install Windows 7. It seems that Windows cannot find the hard drive, and prompts for drivers. I've tried extracting drivers from a Windows server 2008 but Windows said "Couldn't find any signed drivers".

Do I stand a chance of installing Windows 7 on a T420?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you trying to install Windows 7 on a server? From the [tech specs](http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/poweredge-t420/pd):

> Operating System
>
> Microsoft® Windows Server® 2012
>
> Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1, x64 (includes Hyper-V® v2)
>
> Novell® SUSE® Linux Enterprise Server
>
> Red Hat® Enterprise Linux®
>
> Virtualization options:
>
> Citrix® XenServer®
>
> VMware® vSphere® ESX™ and ESXi™
>
> Red Hat Enterprise Virtualization®

It's entirely possible that the hardware you are messing with does not support Windows 7 period, so if you could clarify what your intent is here that would help a lot.

Comment: I need a computer with Windows 7 PCIe access, and that's the only free computer I have. We've managed to install a driver, and partition the disk now, but we get "error 8030001". Also, when changing the BIOS priority of the hard drive, we get the error "BOOTMGR is missing"

Comment: What do you mean by "Windows 7 PCIe access"? Please explain your _intent_ (that includes the end goal).

Answer (score 0):

You can install Windows 7:

- just go to bios setup;
- select SATA mode;
- and be sure it is not in RAID mode - just choose SATA mode